# How do I convert a string to an integer when the string starts with non-numeric characters and leading zeroes?

Tags: delphi

I have some strings which are dynamically created at run time.

The values are generated in sequence with an underscore, leading zeroes and then the sequence number. The format looks like so:

```
_00001  
_00002  
_00003  
_00004

_00098  
_00099  
_00100  
_00101
```

I would like to extract the number part as Integer, ignoring the underscore and leading zeroes.

`StringReplace` can easily remove the underscore part, but how can I extract the number part as I have no way of knowing what the values are?

Some example outputs of how such a function would work:

`_00003` = `3`
`_00098` = `98`
`_00482` = `482`
`_07218` = `7218`
`_14005` = `14005`
`_37585` = `37585`
`_69732` = `69732`

`StringReplace` and `Pos` is what I am thinking, but I am not always sure as to how to fully use `Pos`, and the `StringReplace` method could possibly be messy.

I think all I need to do is check for the first number that is not 0, but maybe I am confusing myself again so really any pointers are welcome.

Comment: Zeroes in front should be ignored. Have you tried StrToInt()?

Comment: `StrToInt(Copy(S, 2, MaxInt))`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use

```
StrToInt(Copy(S, 2))
```

Indeed, `Copy(S, 2)` returns all characters of `S` except the first one, so you'd get `00003`, `00098`, `00482`, etc. And these you can easily convert to the corresponding integers using `StrToInt`.

Comment: How come I never knew you could exclude the third argument of `Copy`? All those times I typed `Copy(S, 2, Length(S));`

Comment: @JerryDodge funny you mention this because the code in Andreas answer worked in XE, then I tried also in Lazarus and it failed, unless you include the Length(S) part. For some reason I like the look of keeping Length(S) in there anyway :)

Comment: @JerryDodge, passing `Length(S)` as 3rd argument is essentially the same as passing `MaxInt` there, since your 2nd argument is `> 1`.

Comment: @FreeConsulting, essentially yes, but `MaxInt` is better because it's constant, so you don't bother with determining of the string length at runtime :-)

Comment: @TLama: Although, for Delphi strings, the length is essentially a constant, too.

Comment: @Andreas, challenge accepted :-) Take a look at disassembly for `I := Length(S)` and compare it with `I := MaxInt`. You have Delphi 2009 like me, so if we have *"standard"* configurations, we should see the same.

Comment: @TLama: Just saying you don't need to iterate until the end of the string!

Comment: @TLama, I do agree. But I was talking about attempting to `Copy` `Length(S)` characters from the string `S` starting from 2nd(!) character. This always results copying to the end of string, just as same as attempting to `Copy` `MaxInt` characters.

Comment: @JerryDodge, strictly speaking you should type `Copy(S, 2, Length(S)-1)`

Comment: @TLama No, no, no MaxInt isn't better. Someday (hopefully) Delphi strings won't be limited to 2GB, and then all the hacked code using MaxInt will be broken. :-( This leave off the last value bit (more technically, an optional parameter) is a lot better and Length(s) will always work, at least. What we really need is slice notation, so we could just type s[2:] and no "Copy" at all to get from the second position to the end.

Comment: @JerryDodge You don't want to know about how I missed PosEx because I skipped the version it appeared in and was using my own code instead. :-(

Comment: @alcade: Re "Hopefully" If I ever have need to have a single string longer than 2GB, I would change my design! In comparison, the web version of Encyclopædia Britannica is only about 0.3GB (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Size_comparisons)

Comment: @alcalde, you're right. However, in this particular case, if you were having a string longer than 2147483648 of digits to represent a number, I doubt you will have a numeric data type to store that large number for the `StrToInt` conversion (it would have been data type larger than `Int17179869184` keeping the bit naming convention). As a compromise I would suggest to have a constant like `MaxStr` with a length limit of the `string` data type.

Comment: @GerryColl Not if your design were, say, finding patterns in DNA sequences. Or you're processing a large amount of data encoded in JSON format.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this :

```
function YourTypeStrToInt(const StrNum: String): Integer;
begin
  Result := StrToInt(Trim(StrNum.Remove(0, 1)));
end;
```

for the old Delphi version:

```
function YourTypeStrToInt(const StrNum: String): Integer;
var
  P: PChar;
begin
 P:=PChar(Trim(StrNum));
 Inc(P);
 Result:=StrToInt(P);
end;
```

Comment: or `Result:=StrToInt(PChar(Trim(StrNum)) + 1);` +1

Comment: +1 for coming back with an updated answer with compatible example.